# Cleared spaces between php still receive warning

Tags: php, sql, e-commerce

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storeadmin/inventory_list.php:68) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/storeadmin/inventory_list.php on line 69

Got the above warning when following an online tutorial. Can't seem to fix it although I have removed spaces between php code.
Any help appreciated, please and thanks!

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
header("location: admin_login.php");
exit();
}
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["id"]);//filter everything but numbers
$manager= preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["manager"]);
$password= preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);

include "../connect_to_mysql.php";//includes file to connect to db
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");

$existCount=mysql_num_rows($sql); //count row
if ($existCount == 0) {

echo "your login does not exist";
exit();
}
?>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);//error report testing
ini_set('display_errors','1');
?>
<?php 
// Delete Item Question to Admin, and Delete Product if they choose
if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
    echo 'Do you really want to delete product with ID of ' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '? <a href="inventory_list.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="inventory_list.php">No</a>';
    exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
    // remove item from system and delete its picture
    // delete from database
    $id_to_delete = $_GET['yesdelete'];
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());
    // unlink the image from server
    // Remove The Pic -------------------------------------------
    $pictodelete = ("../inventory_images/$id_to_delete.jpg");
    if (file_exists($pictodelete)) {
                unlink($pictodelete);
    }
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
    }
    ?>
<?php
//parse form data adds inventory item to database
if(isset($_POST['product_name'])){
$product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
$proddescription = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['proddescription']);
$genre = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['genre']);
$quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);
//this checks if an item already exists under this name
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name' LIMIT 1");
$productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($productMatch > 0){
echo 'Sorry, this item already exists, <a href="inventory_list.php">click here</a>';
exit();
}
//add items to database
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, proddescription, genre, quantity)
VALUES('$product_name','$price','$proddescription','$genre','$quantity')") or die (mysql_error());
$pid = mysql_insert_id();
    // Place image in the folder 
    $newname = "$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
    header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php
//this displays whole list
$product_list="";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
$productCount =mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($productCount>0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id = $row["id"];
$product_name = $row["product_name"];
$price = $row["price"];
$quantity = $row["quantity"];
$product_list.="$id - $product_name - $quantity - $price &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href= 'inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";
}
} else {
$product_list = "There are no products in the store.";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">

<head>
   <title>Inventory List</title>
   <link href="../style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

   <div id="masthead">
   </div>

   <div id="navigation">
      <p><a href="index1.php">Home</a>
      <a href="fiction.php">Fiction</a>
      <a href="travel.php">Travel</a>
      <a href="sport.php">Sport</a>
      <a href="arts.php">Arts & Design</a>
      <a href="cart.php">Shopping Cart</a>
      <a href="account.php">Manage Account</a></p>



   </div>

   <div id="content">
   <div align ="right" style="margin-right:32px;"><a href="inventory_list.php#inventoryForm">+ Add New Item</a></div>
   <div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
   </div>

<h4>Inventory List</h4>
<?php echo $product_list; ?>

<a name = "inventoryForm" id="inventoryForm"></a>
<h3> 
&darr; Add New Item Form &darr;
</h3>
<form action="inventory_list.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
<tr>
<td width="20%">Product Name</td>
<td width="80%"><label>
<input name="product_name" type="text" id="product_name" size="64" />
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product Price</td>
<td><label>
&pound;
<input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="12" />
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description</td>
<td><label>
<input name="proddescription" type="text" id="proddescription" size="64" />
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Genre</td>
<td><label>
<select name="genre" id="genre" />
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
<option value="Travel">Travel</option>
<option value="Sport">Sport</option>
<option value="Arts & Design">Arts & Design</option>
</select>
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product Image</td>
<td><label>
<input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td><label>
<input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" size="4" />
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><label>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add Item" />
</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br />
<br />
</div>

   <div id="footer">
      <p>ADMIN AREA</p>
   </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove the `?><?php` in your code and see if that helps.

Comment: As @iambriansreed - The reason that is happening is because there is still 1x new line between the tags. You can safely take them out without causing any issues.

Comment: @ChrisK: True, but closing and immediately re-opening the PHP tags is useless and is an invitation for problems like this. Better to leave them out, and only terminate the PHP block when necessary.

Comment: Im confused as to what I should be removing from this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
}
?>    <---this will count as a space
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);//error report testing
```

it should be

```
}
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

there's no point in closing php mode then immediately reopening it. You have this construct in multiple locations, and each will have to be fixed.